# What is the meaning of probabilistic polynomial time adversary?

Tags: encryption

I learned about probabilistic polynomial time adversary, but I have some doubt.

- Is probabilistic polynomial time adversary referred to those who attack in polynomial time with the form of probabilistic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean for an adversary to run in PPT?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/17815/what-does-it-mean-for-an-adversary-to-run-in-ppt)

Comment: @Daniel I agree that the title of that other question suggests that it is a dupe. I'll try and fix the title (later) though, because the rest of the question seems to focus on the *probabilistic* part of the term while this question seems to focus on the  *polynomial time* component. The answers are also pretty different from each other for that reason.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ok! Thanks for taking a look at it :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but note as below, the probability is not biased.

From the Lindell, Katz book;

> An algorithm $A$ is said to run in **polynomial time** if there exists a polynomial $p(\cdot)$  such that for every input $x \in \{0,1\}^*$, the computation of $A(x)$ terminates within at most $p(|x|)$ steps.
>
> A **probabilistic algorithm** is one that has the capability of "tossing
> coins", i.e. the algorithm has access to a random source of randomness
> that yields unbiased random bits that are independently equal to 1
> with $1/2$ probability and to 0 with $1/2$ probability.

**Probabilistic Polynomial-time adversary** means; An adversary runs in probabilistic polynomial time algorithm.

---

Different formulation (due to a comment of SEJPM):

- A probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm is a probabilistic algorithm that may only perform a polynomial amount of operations including at most a polynomial number of coin-flips.
- A probabilistic polynomial-time adversary is then any probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: Different formulation: A probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm is a probabilistic algorithm that may only perform a polynomial amount of operations including at most a polynomial number of coin-flips. A probabilistic polynomial-time adversary is then _any_ probabilistic polynomial-time algorithm.

Comment: You should mention that it's a polynomial in the length of the algorithms input. Otherwise the bound on the number of steps is ill defined.

Comment: @SEJPM The difference is immaterial, though. Even if you allow an unbounded number of coin tosses, this does not give the adversary more power because it cannot "use" more than a polynomial number of them.