# big-O (time complexity) for AES (CBC - mode)

Tags: aes, complexity

I have been searching for many days about the time complexity of O(n) for AES (preferably CBC mode). Moreover, I am searching for formal documents like papers/books/standards. I found this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5945606 that says O(1)... I can't believe that! And this: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-15943-0_10 that describes attacks complexity on AES... Has anyone any idea what is the complexity O(n) of AES encryption/decryption?

Comment: There was a dupe for this (AFAIR) Meir Maor answered. AES has 128-bit keyspace as you can see that is $\mathcal{O}(1)$ To have $\mathcal{O}(n)$ complexity one needs some input depending on the value $n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Big-O Encryption Algorithm](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/67540/big-o-encryption-algorithm) see also [What is the time complexity of the basic components of a symmetric cipher?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/63577/18298)

Comment: Just search with AES O(1) to get more answer?

Comment: (Fast accepting and some research -> +1) Note that you can upvote helpful answers to your question...