# limiting number of queries to Enc. or Dec

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, decryption, decryption-oracle

Why do we limit the number of queries to Encryption or Decryption oracles in the security analysis of various encryption schemes to be polynomial in the security parameter n?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of [Why do we focus on polynomial time, rather than other kinds of time?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/62448/18298)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically we only consider adversaries that run in *probabilistic polynomial time* (PPT), to model real world, computationally bounded  adversaries. If an adversary runs in polynomial time, it can only make polynomially-many queries. We wouldn't want to consider adversaries that could literally just try every possible secret key (brute force) in an exponentially-sized keyspace, for example.